# Is there a way find a button by two of its properties in Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to click a button by using puppeteer, and I am trying to find it by two of its properties, `aria-describedby` and `title`, because it doesn't have an ID.
The value of the aria-describedby property is a name I set, however, the last two characters are numbers that changes itselves automatically to random numbers.

I've searched through regexp questions, JS questions, puppeteer's codes, but nothing that actually worked.

The closest I've come with is this:

```
//v1
const arr = await page.$x('//button[starts-with("aria-describedby", "someName")]');
await arr[1].click();

//v2
page.click('button[aria-describedby="someName20"][title="Click button"]');
```

I've tried different codes, but almost always I get `undefined` or `no node found for selector`

Comment: The HTML is exactly [this](http://powerbidax.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/image-14-1024x146.png) (don't mind the red rectangles), the dataset tab for powerbi webview. I want to address the images under the actions column (these are the buttons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try css starts-with selector (`^=`):

```
button[aria-describedby^="someName"][aria-label="Click button"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm lacking html code to go off of so its tough to pinpoint an answer, but whenever i have dynamic selectors to click that need two parameters, i search by contains text:

```
let toClick = await page.$x("//button[contains(text(),'someName20')][contains(text(),'Click button')]");

await toClick[0].click();
```

*Note:* the text() method only works on text nodes (i.e. `<a>someName20</a>`
), but you can interchange the first or second expression in the bracket to query a value of a property instead of the elements text value.

Comment: Didn't work, it says `The string '//button[contains(text(),"ControleEAsdatasetMenu")][contains(text(),"Atualizar agora"]' is not a valid XPath expression.`. The code is `<button class="refreshNow pbi-glyph pbi-glyph-refresh" localize-tooltip="RefreshNow" ng-if="::$ctrl.canRefreshNow()" ng-click="$ctrl.refreshNow()" aria-describedby="ControleEAsdatasetMenu14" use-tooltip-as-aria-label="" title="Atualizar agora" aria-label="Atualizar agora"></button>`  I will try to figure it out anyway. Thanks!